# IELTS test resources

Tags: discussion, resources

I want to prepare for the **IELTS** academic exam, and I am so confused about *the best* *resources*. Do you have any suggestion for me?

And in your opinion, which is better **Collins** or **Cambridge** books for IELTS?

Comment: Start by searching [IELTS exam preparation books](https://ieltsmaterial.com/best-ielts-preparation-books/). The Trainer series is  reliable. You'll always find good tips

Comment: Hi Omar. ELU is not really a language learning site. If you likeStackExchange, then sites at SE that are better for learning are [ell.SE] or [languagelearning.se]

Comment: The question is still off-topic on ELL, it is not a question about learning, or about the English language. @Mitch. Questions asking for resources is fine on meta. But are largely ignored by the community because requests for **best** resources are extremely subjective.

Comment: Reading the classics will help with older language too florid for today's use, but still valuable to recognize. Poe is perfect: short stories with grizzly themes that grab the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing the ‘best’ book to prepare for the IELTS depends on which score you are aiming for and what you believe is your greatest weakness. Is it listening, vocabulary, writing, reading, grammar  or speaking?

For those who you have never taught IELTS and for candidates who need to score 6.0, 6.5 or 7.0, there are a plethora of books to choose from:

- The ***Cambridge IELTS Trainer*** covers all these areas, but not in great detail, it provides advice on how to affront the exam in all its parts.

If vocabulary is weak:

- Cambridge English ***Vocabulary for IELTS Advanced*** help candidates who need to score at least 7.0, especially in the reading, writing and *speaking* section.

Here's a [link recommending the best self-study books](https://englishproficiency.com/ielts/preparation/best-books/) which the OP can peruse at leisure. They *may* even find free pdf versions online. Alternatively, visit the Amazon website in your country and see which IELTS book has the highest number of positive reviews.

On Amazon Italy, *[The Official Cambridge Guide to IELTS Student's Book](https://www.amazon.it/Official-Cambridge-Students-Answers-DVD-ROM/dp/1107620694/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3REJZ5ZNXFFP8&keywords=IELTS&qid=1677408371&sprefix=ielts%2Caps%2C102&sr=8-5)*, has just under 3,600 positive reviews.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I need to score 7.0 at least. For other parts of the exam( speaking, writing, and reading) what is the best resources in your opinion? And thanks again.

Comment: @Omar I haven't used that many books for IELTS. Did my *three* recommendations not convince you? "Best" depends on *your* needs. Any one of the books mentioned in the previous links will likely be helpful.

Comment: Okay, I just want to know more advice and opinions. I appreciate your help.             My regards